# c++ - overloading operator new

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I'am a little bit confused about operator overloading new and delete.
I wrote some test :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    public :

    Test()
    {
        cout << "Test - ctor" <<endl;
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        cout << "Test - dtor" <<endl;
    }

    Test(const Test& t)
    {
        cout << "Test - copy ctor" <<endl;
    }

    Test& operator = (const Test& t)
    {
        cout << "Test - assiment operator" <<endl;
    }

    void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
        cout << "Test - operator new" <<endl;
        return NULL;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << "print" << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
   Test* t = new Test();
   t->print();
   return 0;
}
```

And the output is :

```
Test - operator new                                                                                                                                                                                
Test - ctor                                                                                                                                                                                        
print
```

Now, if I return "NULL" from "new" , why my program doesn't crash when I call to print function?
thanks.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the overload, it's regular undefined behaviour. Try `Test* t = nullptr; t->print();` and see what happens (or doesn't).

Comment: UB is as UB does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `print()` doesn't actually need anything of it's class `Test`. All it does is print a message to `stdout`. Remember that `t->print();` is the same as `print(t);`, your function signature is actually:

```
void print(Test* t);
```

But that's all done by the compiler for you.

`t` just isn't used in the method and thus you're (un)lucky because it runs. This is still just plain undefined behaviour though.

If you absolutely want to see things crash and burn then change your class a bit:

```
class Test
{
    public :

    Test() : x(0)
    {
        cout << "Test - ctor" <<endl;
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        cout << "Test - dtor" <<endl;
    }

    Test(const Test& t)
    {
        cout << "Test - copy ctor" <<endl;
    }

    Test& operator = (const Test& t)
    {
        cout << "Test - assiment operator" <<endl;
    }

    void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
        cout << "Test - operator new" <<endl;
        return NULL;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << "print" << x << endl;
    }

private:
    int x;
};
```

Comment: Thank you . Now I'am understand.

Answer (score 1):

This specific phenomenon has nothing to do with your `operator new` function.

The behaviour on calling a member function through a NULL pointer is *undefined*. Your result is a manifestation of that undefined behaviour.

It just happens to work in your particular case (possibly because your class is just a bag of functions).

(These days it's a good idea to use `nullptr` rather than the old-fashioned and not absolutely correct `NULL`.)

Comment: This is a _much better_ answer than the accepted one which is full of wrong facts and bad advice.

Comment: @MikeVine I don't see any "advice" in my answer. If you disagree with something in the answer, leave a comment.

Comment: @GillBates _...Your functions signature is actually..._ No it isn't. _If you want to see things crash and burn_ No they wont. Undefined Behavoir is undefined. Either the original or your new one may or may not crash depending on many different things including possibly the phase of the moon. Its _Undefined_. This answer says this. Undefined is just that. Its almost never the right thing to work out why something happens after UB.

Comment: @MikeVine Actually, yes it is. And while your case about undefined behaviour is true, in this case the code only shows the OP the "crash" they were hoping for. I never said to rely on it, nevertheless, on every major compiler the behaviour is exactly the same. Which is what the OP wanted to see. You can't rely on it because it's undefined but as far as machine instructions go there's no such thing as undefined behaviour. Also, comment on my answer, not this one, don't pollute Bathsheba's answer.